# Prevent machine in a LAN from receiving a remote shutdown

Tags: remote-shutdown

I'm probably just overreacting, but I recently came across a LAN-scanner that showed me the option "remote shutdown", for all found computers on the scanned network.

Now, how exactly does this work? If I send such a message, will the shutdown happen no matter what, or is it required to have the password/user-name of the user of that other computer.

Mostly I'm wondering: can this be done to me and how do I prevent it?

EDIT: what's more, I had the scanner check for shares. The result being this:
[image]
Double clicking the links opens them in explorer, basically meaning my entire C and F drive(only 2 HD's I have) are completely exposed to anyone in my LAN. Or can I open these because it's my own machine?

Comment: Just make sure the user that sending the command is not among any local admin groups on your PC.

Comment: @r0ca: That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify who is in your admin group, both local and at the domain level. Those people will be able to remotely administer your computer. The drives with the dollar signs are administrative shares and can be disabled by turning off sharing: [MSDN - Disable sharing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314984)

As for the other stuff, you can see here on troubleshooting remote adminstration, which also shows you how to enable (and thus disable) it.
[MSDN - Troubleshoot WMI](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875605#6)

Comment: I'm the only local admin on my machine. So, if I plug my machine in to a Switch and give it a static IP, all the other people within the same subnet would not be able to shut me down?

Comment: Is your computer part of a domain?  If so, administrators on that domain will probably also be able to shutdown/administer your computer remotely. You could probably test this using free tools like Sysinternals psshutdown (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541) I don't know for sure but suspect it uses similar management APIs.